# How to get filename in MODEL to insert into database from the input form?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in using CodeIgniter. I apology if my question is silly.
My model function is as follows:

```
function entry_insert($fname){
$this->load->database();
$maxFileID=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT max(convert(substring( FileID , 1,length(FileID)-4 ) ,unsigned integer)) as val FROM docrepository"));
 // Find the maximum value of FileID
  if ($maxFileID['val']==NULL)
  {
  $temp="1.PDF";
  }
  else
  {
  //$data["FileID"]=(string)(intval(substr($row[0],0,-4))+1).".PDF"; // If there is already file 
  $temp=(string) ($maxFileID['val']+1).".PDF";
  }
   $data=array(

    'FileID'        =>$temp,
   'FileName'       =>$fname,// Not sure whether it will work---I need your suggestion
    'title'         =>$this->input->post('title'),
    'author'        =>$this->input->post('author'),
    'description'   =>$this->input->post('description'),
    'companyName'   =>$this->input->post('companyName'),
    'aircraftModel' =>$this->input->post('aircraftModel'),
    'aircraftNumber'=>$this->input->post('aircraftNumber'),
    'documentType'  =>$this->input->post('documentType'),
    'documentNumber'=>$this->input->post('documentNumber'),
    'sectionNumber' =>$this->input->post('sectionNumber'),
    'dateCreated'   =>$this->input->post('dateCreated'),
    'keywords'      =>$this->input->post('keywords'),
    'notes'         =>$this->input->post('notes')

   );
   $this->db->insert('docrepository',$data);

  }
```

All the data will come from the input form in the view
My objective is to store the original file name is the database and upload the file in the server to a specific format (FileID).
So in this context

1. where should I put my do_upload() function, in model or in controller?
2. how we can get the fileName that have been uploaded by the user in the view?
3. and how we can send the FileID as new filename so that do_upload function can upload the file in the server?

I will appreciate any idea with sample code.

Comment: functions are always in the model. Put the file name in a hidden input called filename, then in your function: `'FileName' => $this->input->post('filename'),` Then, call `$this->do_upload` in your function to upload. Your view should have a form that posts to a function in your controller which calls `entry_insert`. I can't tell if you mean `entry_insert` is different from `do_upload`.

Answer (score 1):

> where should I put my do_upload() function, in model or in controller?

Model is to work with the database so I go with controller in this one.

> how we can get the fileName that have been uploaded by the user in the
>   view?

Well, $_FILES is native from PHP and is accessible in your controller. You can also look at the [Upload class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html). The class have the `data()` function, that returns all information about the file.

```
//sample result of $this->upload->data()
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

> and how we can send the FileID as new filename so that do_upload
>   function can upload the file in the server?

Create a function in the model that returns the new name and set this before start the upload class, for example:

```
//function save in the controller
function save() {
  $fname = $_FILES["input_upload"]["name"];
  $name = $this->model->getNewFileName($fname);
  $config["file_name"] = $name; //this replaces the name of the file on upload
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  if( $this->upload->do_upload() ) {
    $this->model->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the upload in your controller. You can get the file name as a POST variable and send it to the model.

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
$this->model_name->saveFile($_POST['fileName'];
```

Don't forget to clean the data and so on. Hope this helps. I don't really understand what you mean by #3.

Comment: Optionally (and recommended), use CI's input helper to access POSTed data: `$this->input->post('fileName');`

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
echo form_open('your_controller/controller_function');
```

Example:

```
echo form_open('userfiles/saveform');
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public function saveform() 
{
    if($this->userfiles_model->entry_insert())
    {
        $this->load->view('your_view', $array);
    }
}
```

And, `entry_insert` will be a function in your model, which may or may not call `do_upload` which is also in your model.

**EDIT:** My understanding is that the controller is simply the "traffic controller" between the view and the model. Any uploads or database saves should go in the model. The controller is used:

1. to retrieve information from the model and send that information to the view
2. send information to the model from the form which is displayed in the view